# Mysql - Join 2 tables if records in third table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

Table 1 = Customers

```
CREATE TABLE `Customers` (
`customer_id` int NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(5) NOT NULL
)
```

Table 2 = Wallposts

```
CREATE TABLE `wallposts` (
`customer_id` int NOT NULL,
`post` varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Table 3 = Friend_list

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
`customer_id` int NOT NULL,
`friend_id` int NOT NULL
)
```

I need to get a list of all wallposts by friends of a specific customer_id. The friend_id is taken from the customer_id in the customers table

Example output

```
customer_id 2, name John, message hello world
customer_id 4, name Susan, message Customer service sucks
customer_id 7, name Philip, message Customer service is great
```

All those posts belong to friends of customer with customer_id 1.

Comment: You should change your table design. You have to add a new table if you add a manufacturer. A table design should be fix and independent from the data. Use a `buyers` table having a `manufacturer` column.

Comment: So I will ask it in another way then.



I have 3 tables

Table 1 = Customers

Customer_id - Firstname - lastname

Table 2 = Wallposts

Customer_id - message

Table 3 = friend_list

Customer_id - friend_id

How can I get the messages plus customer names of only those customers who are friends?

Comment: Please edit your question, also add example data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

A series of joins should do the trick

```sql
SELECT c.customer_id, c.name, w.post
FROM   friends f
JOIN   customer c ON f.friend_id = c.customer_id
JOIN   wallposts w ON c.customer_id = w.customer_id
WHERE  f.customer_id = 1
```

Comment: How can I include the posts from the customer whose friend posts we are searching for?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it can be as below

```
SELECT
    customers.customer_id, customers.name, wallposts.posts
FROM
    wallposts
INNER JOIN customers ON wallposts.customer_id = customers.customer_id
WHERE wallposts.customer_id IN(SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE customer_id = 1)
```